# Bunch of CIFS VFS errors with SMB mount

Tags: 18.04, smb

I'm currently getting a lot of CIFS VFS errors especially the first line gets repeated a lot.

```
CIFS VFS: Free previous auth_key.response = 0000000000
CIFS VFS: Close unmatched open
CIFS VFS: Error -32 sending data on socket to server
```

This is my fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/downloads--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=ff1c22bc-d67e-47d8-9da9-5ed781e7de2f /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/downloads--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0


//192.168.178.200/Music /music cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/home/downloads/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
//192.168.178.200/Movies /movies cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/home/downloads/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
//192.168.178.200/Series /series cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/home/downloads/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
//192.168.178.200/Audioooks /audiobooks cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/home/downloads/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
//192.168.178.200/eBooks /ebooks cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/home/downloads/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
/dev/sdb /downloads ext4 defaults 0 0
```

I know other people have encountered the same problem and they were able to fix it by adding "cifs vers=3.0" to the fstab.

Thanks for any help!